# Derivation on the effect of temperature on Fermi distribution function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, electronics

With reference to Section **10.7 Effect of Temperature on Fermi Distribution Function** from the text *Solid State Physics*, 2nd ed., M. A. Wahab, the last two equations are given like this:

$E_{F_0}^{3/2} = E_{F}^{3/2}[1+\frac{\pi^2}{8}(\frac{kT}{E_{F}})^2] \\ E_F = E_{F_0}[1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}(\frac{kT}{E_{F_0}})^2]$

where $E_{F}$ is the Fermi energy at any given temperature $T$ and $E_{F_0}$ is the Fermi energy at absolute zero. I tried to solve the first the equation to bring down to second equation but couldn't reach there. I know I think it has to do something with binomial expansion I do not follow how, not unless I take  $E_{F} = E_{F_0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the low-temperature limit is considered here, where $\lambda=T/E_\mathrm{F}\ll1$ is the small parameter. From the first equation we have
$$
E_\mathrm{F_0}=E_\mathrm{F}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lambda^2\right)^{2/3}.
$$
Performing the Taylor expansion, we get
$$
E_\mathrm{F_0}=E_\mathrm{F}\left(1+\frac23\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lambda^2+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^4)\right).
$$
The similar small parameter is $\lambda_0=T/E_\mathrm{F_0}$, which, with taking into account the formulas above, is
$$
\lambda_0=\frac{T}{E_\mathrm{F}}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lambda^2\right)^{-2/3}=\lambda+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^3),
$$
so $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^n)=\mathcal{O}(\lambda_0^n)$.
Then
$$
E_\mathrm{F}=E_\mathrm{F_0}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lambda^2\right)^{-2/3}=E_\mathrm{F_0}\left(1-\frac23\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lambda^2+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^4)\right)=\\
E_\mathrm{F_0}\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\lambda_0^2+\mathcal{O}(\lambda_0^4)\right),
$$
which is the desired second equation.